# Is sampling by even/odd serial numbers a simple random sample?

Tags: sample, stratification

I'm working on a project where each member of the population has a serial number. Each serial number is issued sequentially, so smaller serial numbers reflect older records. I'm drawing a sample of every *i*th serial number. Is this a simple random sample or a stratified random sample? I know that older records behave differently from younger records and this method ensures that I'm sampling fairly across age groups. I'm just not sure if I should call it simple or stratified or something else.

Comment: You know that the old records do not behave the same as the new ones, so immediately you have a major violation of the $iid$ assumption in most of the statistical methods people know.

Comment: Long time ago someone tried to sample residents of a small town randomly by phone numbers. (Chose numbers ending in 2.) Turned out business and doctors all has numbers ending in 0, other subscribers might have multiple-party lines so last number showed number of parties on the line. // You can never know for sure how serial numbers are really assigned.

Comment: It is technically not a random sample. In the best case, it might effectively be random, but that makes strong assumptions about how serial numbers are assigned and could run into some issues.